# Obtener elementos de etiqueta <body> individualmente

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```js
function obtener(){

  var contador = 1;

  $("body").each(function(){
  
    console.log(contador + " " + $(this).text() + "\n");
    console.log("----------------------------------\n");
  
    contador++;
  
  });

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="level-1">
    <li class="item-i">I</li>
    <li class="item-ii">II
      <ul class="level-2">
        <li class="item-a">A</li>
        <li class="item-b">B
          <ul class="level-3">
            <li class="item-1">1</li>
            <li class="item-2">2</li>
            <li class="item-3">3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item-c">C</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-iii">III</li>
  </ul>

<input type="submit" onclick="obtener();" value="Obtener">

</body>

</html>
```

El codigo muestra primero una lista organizada, con ciertos textos y viñetas, en fin, el  de este ejemplo es solo demostrativo.

Lo que pretendo hacer es obtener el texto de cada uno de los elementos contenidos dentro de la etiqueta  de manera individual.

He intentado con la funcion [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) de [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), de la siguiente manera:

```
$("body").each(function(){

    console.log(contador + " " + $(this).text() + "\n");
    console.log("----------------------------------\n");

});
```

Pero, cuando se imprime el mensaje de `console.log`, todo se muestra como un solo texto, es decir, en lugar de imprimirse asi:

```
I
---------
II
---------
A
---------
B
---------
```

Se esta imprimiendo asi:

```
I
II

    A
    B

        1
        2
        3
---------------------
```

No he encontrado documentacion al respecto, mas que la de jQuery y el manejo de la funcion [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), pero no entiendo porque imprime todo como un solo texto, siendo que este "recorre" cada uno de los elementos contenidos en el selector.

Comment: ese selector solo selecciona al `body`. El `each` es sobre la seleccion, no sobre los elementos internos de la seleccion. Hay varias formas (via `children()` por ej), pero ese resultado es complicado de obtener. Por que si tomas los hijos el, `<li>` por ejemplo, su texto renderiza como todos los elementos internos.. asi que el problema se repite... exactamente que quieres lograr?

Comment: @EmanuelVe Gracias por tu comentario, lo que necesito hacer es poder a todos los textos que se encuentren en un sitio X, es decir, al texto contenido por las etiquetas. Es decir, con una funcion N si encuentro una etiqueta <a>, poder acceder al texto que esta contiene.

Comment: ¿Lo que necesitas es acceder al texto de cada una de las etiquetas `<a>`? Eso se puede hacer con `$("a").each(function(){..})`

Comment: @MatiasOlivera No solo a las etiquetas <a>, sino a cualquier texto que este en el html.

Comment: estaria correcto un array asi: `['I','II','A','B']` ? (si tomaramos el `li` como base) ?

Comment: @IvanBotero ¿Por qué `I,II,A,B` y no `I,II,A,B,1,2,3,C,III` o `I,II,A,B,C,III` o...? ¿Cómo determinas cuántos niveles o en qué orden? La pregunta no está muy clara en ese sentido

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Me refiero a todos los elementos, sin importar cuantos niveles, lo que necesito es acceder a los textos para poder buscar textos dentro del DOM.

Comment: ¿Y qué quieres que se devuelva? ¿Un array con los textos o con los elementos que contienen esos textos? Y aparte, ¿te importa que sea una solución con JavaScript puro o tiene que ser usando jQuery?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Si bien en la pregunta menciono la impresion de los textos, en estos puntos del problema, no importa si es un arreglo, una lista, lo unico que necesito son los textos que se encuentren en el html :)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro No importa si es javascript o Jquery, esto lo uso para una extension de Chrome, alli no hay problema con el lenguaje a usar

Comment: Ok, perfecto. Ahora te escribo una respuesta. Y sabiendo que lo que quieres es que funcione en Chrome, mejor que mejor (porque no iba a funcionar del todo en IE/Edge :P)

Comment: IE funciona solo para descargar Chrome! Te agradezco tu ayuda, me ha quedado un poco grande :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parece que lo que quieres es leer todos los nodos de texto independientes que hay en una página, sin necesidad de que estén agrupados; para ello puedes usar JavaScript puro y [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker). El objeto `TreeWalker` representa los nodos de un subárbol del documento y su posición.

Entonces lo que podrías hacer es crear un `TreeWalker` y atravesar todos los nodos del `body` quedándote sólo con los nodos de texto. Eso es algo que se puede definir cuando creas el `TreeWalker` con [`createTreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker):

```
treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(raiz, queMostrar, filtro, expansionEntidadferencia);
```

donde:

- `raiz` es el nodo que se utilizará como origen para crear el TreeWalker (sólo se explorará el subárbol a partir de ese elemento), en tu caso quieres que sea el `body`.
- `queMostrar` es un parámetro opcional para indicar qué tipos de nodos quieres obtener. Puede tener diferentes valores que harán que se muestren unos valores u otros, en tu caso quieres que se muestren sólo nodos de texto por lo que deberías usar `NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT`. Puedes ver la lista completa en el enlace de arriba.
- `filtro` es un parámetro opcional para pasar un filtro a los nodos encontrados por `queMostrar`.
- `expansionEntidadReferencia` es un parámetro booleano opcional que indica que si se descarta una `EntityReference` entonces todo el subárbol que sale de ella se descartará también al mismo tiempo.

Un *problema* de usar `TreeWalker` es que no está soportado por todos los navegadores. No está disponible para versiones de Internet Explorer anteriores a la 9, y el soporte es básico para Edge... pero como dices que lo quieres para un plugin de Chrome, no deberías tener problema.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo con tu código:

```js
function obtener(){

  var raiz = document.querySelector("ul.level-1");
  var queMostrar = NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT;
  var filtro = { acceptNode: function(node) { 
    if ( !/^\s*$/.test(node.data) ) { 
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT; 
    } } };
  var expansion = false;
  
  var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(raiz, queMostrar, filtro, expansion);

  var nodos = [];

  while(treeWalker.nextNode()) 
    nodos.push(treeWalker.currentNode.data.trim());
    
  console.log(nodos);
  return nodos;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="level-1">
    <li class="item-i">I</li>
    <li class="item-ii">II
      <ul class="level-2">
        <li class="item-a">A</li>
        <li class="item-b">B
          <ul class="level-3">
            <li class="item-1">1</li>
            <li class="item-2">2</li>
            <li class="item-3">3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item-c">C</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-iii">III</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" onclick="obtener();" value="Obtener">
</body>
```

Nota: el filtro es para evitar que se inserten "falsos positivos" en el array. Lo que hace es que no acepta el nodo si sólo está formado por separadores y espacios en blanco. No es mío, [lo he sacado de esta página de MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeFilter#Example).

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la respuesta Alvaro, no conocia el TreeWalker, es lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 1):

Para recorrer todos los elementos dentro de la etiqueta `body` necesitas utilizar el selector universal `*` tal que así:

```js
function obtener() {
  $('body *').each(function(indice, elementoHTML) {
    console.log(indice + " " + $(elementoHTML).text() + "\n");
    console.log("----------------------------------\n");
  });
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="level-1">
    <li class="item-i">I</li>
    <li class="item-ii">II
      <ul class="level-2">
        <li class="item-a">A</li>
        <li class="item-b">B
          <ul class="level-3">
            <li class="item-1">1</li>
            <li class="item-2">2</li>
            <li class="item-3">3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item-c">C</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-iii">III</li>
  </ul>

  <input type="submit" onclick="obtener();" value="Obtener">

</body>

</html>
```

Fíjate, que no es necesario manejar un contador fuera de la función `each`, ya que esta incluye el índice como primer parámetro, y el elemento que se trata como el segundo.